# PHP unzip nested zip files

Tags: php, zip, unzip, 7zip

How to unzip the nested zip files using php, here I found some other relative answers based on that I can extract zip for single iteration but I can't able to for multiple iteration dynamically

My zipped directory structure like this,

**Folder**

- Root.zip

  - rootSampleA.txt
  - rootSampleB.txt
  - 1_iterationA.zip

    - 1_sampleA.txt
  - 1_iterationB.zip

    - 2_iterationA.zip

      - 3_iterationA.zip
    - 2_iterationB.zip

      - 2_sampleB1.txt
      - 2_sampleB2.txt

Comment: Take a look: [enter link description here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4367/extracting-nested-zip-files)

Comment: I would guess, the magic you are looking for is called `Recursion`.

Comment: Is this PHP related? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes, I looking like -r  @Rabban

Comment: While this is possible to do, it's probably a lot quicker if you just use `gunzip -r` instead of using `unzip` and coding a recursive loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I tried so far @apokryfos
I can bring the file for 1st Iteration only using this script

```
private function unZip($file, $dirname){
            exec("unzip".$file, $output, $exitStatus);
            if($exitStatus){
                $this->readFile($output)
            }
        }


private function readFile($fileList){
            if(count($fileList) > 0){
                for($i = 1; $i < count($zipList); $i++){
                    if(preg_match('/[.zip]$/i', $zipList[$i])){
                        $this->unZip($zipList[$i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What I want to do more for multiple iteration dynamically

Comment: You should update your question with this instead of posting it as an answer